# How to check a CGDisplay is iPad by sidecar on MacOS?

Tags: macos, sidecar

As MacOS and iPad support sidecar now, CGGetActiveDisplayList provides the list of displays contains iPad when sidecar working, but how to check witch CGDisplay is the iPad?

```
  CGDirectDisplayID displays[10] = {0};
  uint32_t count;
  CGError err = CGGetActiveDisplayList(10, displays, &count);
  printf("%d %d\n", displays[0], displays[1]);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    CGDisplayModeRef mode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(displays[i]);
    int32_t io = CGDisplayModeGetIODisplayModeID(mode);
    uint32_t io_flag = CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags(mode);
    bool usable = CGDisplayModeIsUsableForDesktopGUI(mode);
    size_t width = CGDisplayModeGetPixelWidth(mode);
    size_t height = CGDisplayModeGetPixelHeight(mode);
    printf("i: %d io: %d usable: %s, io flag: 0x%x, pixel size: %dx%d\n",i, io, usable ? "T": "F", io_flag, width, height);
  }
```

Output:

```
i: 0 io: 8 usable: T, io flag: 0x7, pixel size: 2880x1800
i: 1 io: 0 usable: T, io flag: 0x2000007, pixel size: 2576x1892
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution? Struggling with the same problem.